DropdownSearch rebuild my widget infinite times when I pass selectedItem(initial value) in it
Widget singleDropdownSearch( //here index is not mandatory and only for the singleDropdownSearch in listview or any loop
    context,
    List<MenuItem> listMenu,
    void Function(MenuItem?, [int?, dynamic]) callback,
    selectedMenuItem,
    refName,
    mandatory,
    readOnly,
    [index, fieldState]
    ) {

  return SizedBox(


width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
  child: DropdownSearch<MenuItem>(
    autoValidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,

    popupProps: PopupProps.dialog(
     
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, MenuItem item, bool isSelected) {
        // print(isSelected);
        return Container(
          // margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
              //                    <--- top side
              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
              width: 1,
            )),
            // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(item.name.toString()),
          ),
        );
      },
      showSelectedItems: false,
      showSearchBox: true,
      searchFieldProps: TextFieldProps(
        // controller: _userEditTextController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Search $refName",
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
          prefixIcon: const IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      // disabledItemFn: (String s) => s.startsWith('I'),
    ),
    items: listMenu,
    enabled: !readOnly && listMenu.isNotEmpty,
    itemAsString: (MenuItem u) => u.name,
    dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
      dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: mandatory ? "$refName*" : refName,
        hintText: "Select $refName",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
      ),
    ),

    onChanged: (value) {
      index == null ? callback(value, null, fieldState) : callback(value, index, fieldState);
    },
    selectedItem: selectedMenuItem,
    validator: (value) {
      return value == null && mandatory ? "Please add $refName" : null;
    },
  ),
    ),
  );
}

My DropdownSearch rebuilds my widget infinite times when I pass selectedItem(initial value) in it. How can I fix this?
